# lock with while loop on multthread application form c# blocking all threads on single core machine

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am having a problem with my multi-threaded app on windows form C# application. This application works fine on multicore machine, but then when it runs in a single core machine all the threads hang. I'm using `backgroundWorker`, code follow as this:

```
 class custonTime // delay class
 {
     public void sleep_sec(int sleep)
     {
         int time_now = Environment.TickCount;
         int time_sleep = sleep;
         while ((Environment.TickCount - time_now) < time_sleep) ;
     }
 }
```

When I press a button on UI the flags `action` and `doAlways` are set to `true` and the following backgroundworkers are started. The backgorundworker1 await and fire the task on right time the other one does the task:

```
 private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
     while(action)
     {
         if(doItAlways)
         {
             //do important tasks
         }
         if(task1)
         { 
             //do things
             task1 = false;
         }
         if(task2)
         { 
             //do things
             task1 = false;
         }
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    task1=true;
    manegerTimewr2.sleep_sec(12000);//call delay class to wait 12 secs
    task2=true;
    manegerTimewr2.sleep_sec(12000);//call delay class to wait 12 secs
}
```

My delay class lock not just my `backgorundworker1` but the `backgroundworker2` as well, make impossible to do the tasks fired by flag `doItAlways`, the application is only released when the while loop finish.

And it just happens on single core machine only.

Is there another method? A direct and easy method to hang a thread until elapse some time without block the other ones?

**Note `Thread.Sleep` won't work because the time elapsed varies too much on different machines.**

Comment: A really tight loop like this ... while ((Environment.TickCount - time_now) < time_sleep) ; ... will seriously hog your CPU and is unlikely to yield any processing time to other threads.

Comment: its is exactly what is happens, what can i do to prevent it?

Comment: This code is bad in more than one way.  Never use a bool to signal between threads, there's no guarantee that another thread can see the value change.  Use an AutoResetEvent instead.  And never write a hot wait loop, at least use Thread.Sleep().  And there's no point at all in using two threads here, the first one can simply delay by itself.  Pick up a book about threading from your local library or bookstore, you are not doing it right at all.

Comment: sorry my code is rubbish =D , however have implemented AutoResetEvent on code, little more trickier but same result, thread sleep cannot be used because need to control time, both thread are necessary because i need to access a automation system  and this cannot be done by diferent thread

Comment: Please explain how "the time elapsed varies too much on different machines".  You own code ought to use `TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond` if it was meant to work the same on all possible implementations of .NET.  You should also look at the various Timer classes in .NET and at TPL as a better way of managing tasks.

Comment: How precise do you need the elapsed time to be?  This may be impossible to guarantee in C#; Windows is not a real-time operating system.  Especially if you're running multiple threads on a single-core machine.

Comment: this application need to wait some seconds until change the task, Ian Mercer is right my `TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond`has same effect then `thread.sleep`, Will try to figure out how to hang a thread with timer class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that `BackgroundWorker` use a thread pool internally which contains usually the same number of threads as you have CPUs/cores on the machine. Therefore on a single-CPU machine you'll have only one thread processing BackgroundWorkers, I guess they are scheduled sequentially so the first one runs both `sleep_sec` calls, and only *after* that, the second one starts.

On a multi-core machine on the other hand, you have more threads in the thread pool, therefore it works as you expect it.

You could use either a "normal" `Thread` (together with `Thread.Sleep`, dont use a `while` loop) for the "waiting", since this doesn't require any UI interaction. You could also just use a `Timer` object, which is meant for exactly this purpose (firing an event after a specified amount of time).

Answer (score 0):

Implement waiting for a specified amount of time with this method: [Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `BackgroundWorker`, instead launch a new `Thread`, and set the `ThreadPriority` for that thread manually.  Then you'll be able to use `Thread.Sleep` and it *should* work more precisely since the thread is higher priority.  Here's about what you should end up with:

```
void Run()
{
    // some initialization stuff
    new Thread(DoWork1) { Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal }.Start();
    new Thread(DoWork2) { Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest }.Start();
}

private void DoWork2()
{
    while (action)
    {
        if (doItAlways)
        {
            //do important tasks
        }
        if (task1)
        {
            //do things
            task1 = false;
        }
        if (task2)
        {
            //do things
            task1 = false;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}

private void DoWork1()
{
    task1 = true;
    Thread.Sleep(12000);//call delay class to wait 12 secs
    task2 = true;
    Thread.Sleep(12000);//call delay class to wait 12 secs
}
```